# I am Routing Node.js package

Tags: node.js

This is my localServer configuration

2. Step 1 'npm install'
3. Step 2 'npm init'
4. Step 3 'npm install express'

I am still learning how to use stack overflow please have some patience. I am trying to post the code then I will ask my question. There won't be a point for me to ask the question when my code is not shown.

Code:

## This is server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = 3000;
var routes = require('./routes.js');
app.use('/', routes);
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Server started on port ' + port);
});
```

## This is my routes.js file

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var eventManagement = require('./js/server/eventManagement.js');
var organizerManagment = require('./js/server/organizerManagement.js')
var routes = function () {
    var router = require('express').Router();

    router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true
    }));

    router.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + "/views/index.html");
    });

    // Organizer
    router.get('/organizer', function (req, res) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + "/views/organizer.html");
    });

    router.get('/css/*', function (req, res) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + req.originalUrl);
    });

    router.get('/js/*', function (req, res) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + req.originalUrl);
    });

    router.get('/events', function (req, res) {
        res.send(eventManagement.getEvents());
    });

    router.post('/events', function (req, res) {
        var data = req.body;

        var event = {
            name: data.name,
            description: data.description,
            start: {
                date: data.startDate,
                time: data.startTime
            },
            end: {
                date: data.endDate,
                time: data.endTime
            }
        };

        eventManagement.addEvent(event);
    });

    //organizer
    router.get('/organizers', function (req, res) {
        res.send(organizerManagment.getOrganizers());
    });

    router.post('/organizers', function (req, res) {
        var data = req.body;

        var organizers = {
            name: data.name,
            company: data.company
        };

        organizerManagment.addOrganizers(organizers.name,organizers.company);
    });

    return router;
};
module.exports = routes();
```

## This is organizerManagement.js

```
var organizers = [
    {
        name: "Joanne Wong",
        company: "Singtel"
    },
    {
        name: "Johnathan Lim",
        company: "NCS"
    }
];
var organizerManagement = {
    addOrganizers: function (n, c) {
        var neworganizers = {
            name: n,
            company: c
        }
        organizers.push(neworganizers);
    },
    getOrganizers: function () {
        return organizers;
    }
};
module.exports = organizerManagement;
```

## This is organizer.html

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css">
    <title>Organizer Management</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Current Organizer</h2>
    <ul class="organizers"></ul>
    <h2>Add Oragnizer</h2>
    <section class="addNewOrganizer">
        <form action="/organizers" method="POST">
            <label for="name">Organizer Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br>

            <label for="company">Company:</label>
            <input type="text" id="company" name="company"><br>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </section>
    <script src='../js/client/jquery-3.4.1.min.js'></script>
    <script src='../js/client/organizer.js'></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What's the question?  You need to describe a clear question.

Answer (score 0):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = 3000;
var routes = require('./routes.js');
app.use('/', routes);
app.listen(port, function () {
        console.log('Server started on port ' + port);
});
```